# How to know my Ram in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I know that how to check my ram and here is my ram.

[image]

But from some resources, I found that if I have more than 4 GB ram and still using Windows 7 32 bit, it would show only 4 GB ram because Windows 7 32 bit only support 4 GB ram. So, it is possible that I originally have more than 4 GB ram but this is saying 4 GB ram. So, How to determine how much ram I have? (I don't wanna open my CPU/other hardware)

Comment: "But from some resources, I found that if I have more than 4 GB ram", show us an image.

Comment: I didn't mean that I have more than 4 GB ram. I mean that from some resources I found that if someone has more than 4 GB ram, Windows 7 32 bit would show only 4 GB because it doesn't support more than 4 GB ram.

Comment: Restart the PC and check the total RAM from the BIOS.

Comment: The dialog in your screenshot already shows the physical amount as well as the actually usable amount (subject to hardware and software limitations).

Comment: @rajin100000 - It would show the correct amount but the usable memory would be limited to 4 GB.  You have 4 GB installed in your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could boot into the BIOS and look for details about the RAM.

The BIOS knows exactly how much RAM you have got.

Answer (score 0):

You can open command prompt (type **cmd** in the Start Menu), in the opened window type *systeminfo |findstr /i "Total Physical Memory"* this will show the total amount of physical memory and some info about used and and available memory.

Also you can use wmi to get info:
*wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, DeviceLocator, Capacity, Speed*
this will show you every memory module and its capacity.